# Merging ContextMenus that are not data bound

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

There seems to be many variations of this question, but none that deal with my scenario.

I have a UserControl that is used in several places. The control has a context menu, but some of its parents also have context menus. The parent context menus are not databound, i.e. they look like this:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Do Something" Click="DoSomethingMenuItem_Click" />
</ContextMenu>
```

I can walk up the logical tree and find the parent context menu, but I can't find a way to duplicate the MenuItems (I have to duplicate them because they are only allowed one parent).

I think I am asking a very similar question to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177298/how-to-merge-wpf-contextmenus But it has not been answers so I'm still searching!

Please don't suggest I data bind the parent control and use composite collections - there are too many places this is used to make that feasable!

Comment: It sounds like you tried duplicating the menu items, but ran into problems. Can you explain what issues you had duplicating the menu items?

Comment: I've solved this issue by duplicating the menu items. I second Nathan's question -- why don't you duplicate them?  (You CAN in fact copy click handlers using reflection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly WPF has no direct way to merge context menus (rather menuitems) from the visual / logical tree of controls.

One way yu can acheive it is instead of setting the direct context menu property of your control, implement an attached property say MergedContextMenu which will be of type context menu.

Now in the property changed event...

1. Create a temporary context menu say currentContextMenu.
2. Clone the menuitems from the current value i.e. (e.NewValue as ContexteMenu).Items. Add these cloned menuitems into the currentContextMenu.
3. Traverse the logical tree and perform step 2 for each context menu found until your desired ancestor is reached.
4. Assign this currentContextMenu to the actual ContextMenu property i.e. ((UIElement)depObj).ContexteMenu = currentContextMenu.

Use the following code for Clone method....

```
public static UIElement cloneElement(UIElement orig){
if (orig == null)
    return (null);
string s = XamlWriter.Save(orig);
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader, new XmlReaderSettings());
return (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

}

Comment: This is not a solution unfortunately because XamlWriter.Save() does not serialize the event handers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx

Comment: I though u are using MVVM coz instead of events you will use commands and they will serialize.  But you can always get event handlers using reflection while u r traversing the logical tree and finding the parent control content menu's menuitems ... isnt it? Anyways the solution worked like charm in my case due to MVVM.

Comment: We are stuck with an architechture that isn't MVVM so that's not an option. I've seen reflection solutions for getting the delegate in WinForms, but not WPF. If you can show me how I'll give you the bounty!

Comment: @Darren, well the bounty is definitely a lucrative offer :-) .... Anyways if you "know" how to get Invocation list of event handlers for an event in winforms, it will also work the same way in WPF... coz the reflection isnt UI framework specific but core .Net based.... Just for your reference one of the ways to raise events (and thus execute  event handlers using reflection) is specified here.... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/44b0d573-5c53-47b0-8e85-6056cbae95b0/ ...   Invocation list can be used to even add handlers to for our cloned menuitems...

Comment: The problem is not reflection based, it is that WPF introduces the idea of a RoutedEvent (with tunnelling or bubbling) that is not just a delegate as in winforms.

Comment: if your existing design has really cryptic bubbling or tunneling of routed events then this is where we have to stop :(... but let me remind you that WPF has ots own set of reflection methods to deal specifically with routed events and dependency properties. E.g. You can also get Routed events and their handler invocation list... like this... EventManager.GetRoutedEvents(UIElement myelement)... in this you can check for Click event and then find all of its handlers...

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by changing the requirements, but thank you for all your useful suggestions. I have marked this as the answer because although it doesn't solve my problem, I think it will be helpful for many others.

Comment: I solved the problem in a similar way, wrapping the functionality in a user control which consumes the temporary context menu and clones its items.  I discovered I needed to copy the Command, CommandParameter, and Style of the original, which were apparently not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Add the MenuItems from each original ContextMenu to a temporary list object, remove them from the original ContextMenus Items collection, and then add them all to the new ContextMenu. So long as the MenuItems are not contained on more than one ContextMenu at once you will be fine.

Comment: This solution only works if there is one child that wants to inherit the menu. Unfortunatly in my scenario I have many children.